# Check from theme's .tpl file for enabled module?

Tags: prestashop

How can I check in theme's .tpl file with "If" operator is there enabled module(s) in a certain hook?

Comment: basicaly you shouldn't do this 'logic' in template files

Comment: Could you tell me where I should implement this "logic"? My idea is if there is no enabled module in the hook to hide it with its surrounding html markup for exm. left column, so I can have only right column and body.

Answer (score 0):

```
{if !empty($hook_name)}
 {$hook_name}
{/if}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should awoid code-only answers. You should add some description.

Answer (score 0):

I do not still find any reason to do this checking. But anyway, there is a solution.
Surround your code in template by:

```
{if $some_modules_enabled}
...
{/if}
```

And put the below code in a controller, ex: FrontController.php

```
$id_hook = Hook::get($name_of_the_hook);
$some_modules_enabled = false;
foreach ( Hook::getModulesFromHook($id_hook) as $row ) {
    if ( Module::isEnabled( $row['name'] ) ) {
        $some_modules_enabled = true;
        break;
    }
}
$this->context->smarty->assign('some_modules_enabled', $some_modules_enabled);
```